# HP Pavilion dv6000 QuickPlay power on

Tags: hp-pavilion

I have a question for HP Pavilion dv6000 owners.
If your laptop is powered down, and you press the QuickPlay button or the DVD button (NOT the power button), does the laptop start up?

More info:

I am asking this because I have got a hold of a broken HP dv6000. If I power it up, the power light lights up, and then the laptop powers down. It seems to be because of a broken motherboard.
But the laptop does the same thing if you press the QuickPlay or DVD buttons, and I want to know if that's supposed to happen, or if it's something else that is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed the laptop, and yes, it does power up if you press the QuickLaunch buttons ;)

Comment: How did you fix the laptop?

Comment: I bought a used motherboard that worked, and replaced the whole motherboard. A few weeks after that, I saw [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GPb6TRmKuzo) and decided to give it a try, since I had nothing to lose. I followed the instructions in that video and I managed to fix the original broken motherboard. Now I have a spare motherboard in case the used one I bought will fail (it hasn't failed yet, and it has been almost 3 years). I don't know how long the repair will hold because I haven't used the repaired motherboard at all (except to test that the repair worked).

Comment: Did you use a pentorch too, or something else to heat it?

Comment: I used a pentorch, something that is similar to [this](http://i00.i.aliimg.com/wsphoto/v0/580784226/3pcs-Wireless-font-b-Butane-b-font-Gas-font-b-Soldering-b-font-Pencil-font-b.jpg).